# Unable to play RoadRash on Window 10

Tags: windows-10, road-rash

I downloaded and installed RoadRash, but as soon as I play, this appears:

[image]

What can I do to start playing the game?

Comment: Hi 5, can you explain what the problem is? I'm not familiar with the game, so can't know what the game shpuld look like. I expect it has to do with the black field?

Comment: Which Road Rash is it? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Road_Rash), there's at least 8 Road Rash games.

Comment: its ROADRASH 1991, the first version

Comment: Actually, I downloaded the game as directed per the video [ https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_YtXaC6Ies ] and it starts successfully and when I go for playing the game , this display the above screenshot.